# Is there any difference between mmap vs mmap64?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, mmap

On a 64-bit machine, is there any difference between `mmap` vs `mmap64`?

There are other such as `fstat64` vs `fstat`.

*answer*:
On a 64-bit Ubuntu 18 LTS,
Verified that mmap and mmap64 func addr are the same.
off_t and off64_t are 64-bit.

fstat/stat able to return > 2 GiB file size.

code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << sizeof(off_t) << endl;

    void* a = (void*)&mmap64;
    void * b = (void*)&mmap;
    cout <<  (a ==b) << endl; // same addr 

    a = (void*)&fstat64;
    b = (void*)&fstat;
    cout << (a==b) << endl; // diff addr but able to return > 2 GiB size
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> On a 64-bit machine, is there any difference between mmap vs mmap64?

None.

The *64 interfaces were introduced to enable [Large File Support](http://www.opengroup.org/platform/lfs.html) on 32-bit systems. It makes no difference on 64-bit systems.

However, the 64-bit interfaces are not actually exposed to users directly (not part POSIX). So you should not use the *64 interfaces directly. If you happen to need them on 32-bit systems, then use [feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) of glibc (e.g., `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`).

> > Macro: _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
> >
> > This macro determines which file system interface shall be used, one replacing the other. Whereas _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE makes the 64 bit interface available as an additional interface, _FILE_OFFSET_BITS allows the 64 bit interface to replace the old interface.
> >
> > If _FILE_OFFSET_BITS is undefined, or if it is defined to the value 32, nothing changes. The 32 bit interface is used and types like off_t have a size of 32 bits on 32 bit systems.
> >
> > If the macro is defined to the value 64, the large file interface replaces the old interface. I.e., the functions are not made available under different names (as they are with _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE). Instead the old function names now reference the new functions, e.g., a call to fseeko now indeed calls fseeko64.
> >
> > This macro should only be selected if the system provides mechanisms for handling large files. On 64 bit systems this macro has no effect since the *64 functions are identical to the normal functions.
> >
> > This macro was introduced as part of the Large File Support extension (LFS).

Answer (score 0):

> The mmap64() function is identical to the mmap() function except that it can be used to map memory from files that are larger than 2 gigabytes into the process memory. The mmap64() function is a part of the large file extensions.

from [here](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/mmap.3.asp)